# Nullable return types for methods

Tags: types, nullable

Hy, just for curiosity..
If I have a method with return type nullable int : int?
When I called the method i can do it in 2 ways:
 var v=method();
and also
method().

Can somebody give me some arguments why the second case is possible?
It's because of the nullable type?Or it's something feature of .NET Framework 4?

thank you

Comment: You mean, calling a method and ignoring its return value? Isn't that always possible, with all return types?

Comment: yes...i mean it is not neccesary for a variable to call the method

Answer (score 0):

For start

`T?` is short represent of generic class `Nullable<T>`

It is a wrapper for primitive types because they are not nullable.
(char byte bool int float long double)

```
public Nullable<int> x; // x = null
public int x; // x = 0
```

You can write it long or short way.

```
public Nullable<int> x;
public int? x;
```

Regarding to question.

```
public int? getValue();

var x = getValue();
getValue(); // why is this allowed
```

Because it is how it work like everywhere in any language.